# Count an IOrderedEnumerable without consuming it

Tags: c#, performance, linq, reflection, ienumerable

What I want to do, short version:

```
var source = new[]{2,4,6,1,9}.OrderBy(x=>x);
int count = source.Count; // <-- get the number of elements without performing the sort
```

---

*Long version:*

To determine the number of elements in an *IEnumerable*, it is neccessary to iterate over all elements. This could potentially be a very expensive operation.

If the *IEnumerable* can be cast to *ICollection*, then the count can be determined quickly without iterating. The LINQ Count() method does this automatically.

The function *myEnumerable.OrderBy()* returns an *IOrderedEnumerable*. An *IOrderedEnumerable* can obviously not be cast to *ICollection*, so calling *Count()* will consume the whole thing.

But sorting does not change the number of elements, and an *IOrderedEnumerable* has to keep a reference to its source. So if that source is an *ICollection*, it should be possible to determine the count from the *IOrderedEnumerable* without consuming it.

My goal is to have a library method, that takes an *IEnumerable* with n elements, and then for example retrieves the element at position n/2;

I want to avoid iterating over the *IEnumerable* twice just to get its count, but I also want to avoid creating an unnecessary copy if at all possible.

---

Here is a skeleton of the function I want to create

```
public void DoSomething(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    int count; // What we do with the source depends on its length

    if (source is ICollection)
    {
        count = source.Count(); // Great, we can use ICollection.Count
    }
    else if (source is IOrderedEnumerable)
    {
        // TODO: Find out whether this is based on an ICollection, 
        // TODO: then determine the count of that ICollection
    }
    else
    {
        // Iterating over the source may be expensive, 
        // to avoid iterating twice, make a copy of the source
        source = source.ToList();
        count = source.Count();
    }

    // do some stuff

}
```

Comment: LINQ is unfortunately designed in a way that makes this completely impossible.

Comment: @SLaks: Often "completely impossible" turns out to be possible.  I think you could do this with Expression tree, but it's beyond my capability.

Comment: Could you create your own wrapper class to hold the original source, and also apply any orderings when required?

Comment: Why don't you just count before sorting?

Comment: I'd like to create a library function that can be called without deeper understanding of its inner workings required. Of course I could have the caller pass the count as an additional parameter to DoSomething(), or require that source is some IMyCustomOrderedEnumerable, but both seem cumbersome and inelegant.

Comment: @MichaelBray: Expression trees would only help if you put the entire LINQ query in an expression tree, then parse out the original input.  You're right; I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's think what this code actually looks like:

```
var source = new[]{ 2, 4, 6, 1, 9 }.OrderBy(x => x);
int count = source.Count();
```

It is same as

```
int count = Enumerable.Count(Enumerable.OrderBy(new[]{ 2, 4, 6, 1, 9 }, x => x));
```

Result of `Enumerable.OrderBy(new[]{ 2, 4, 6, 1, 9 }, x => x)` is passed into `Count` extension. You cannot avoid `OrderBy` execution. And thus it is non-streaming operator, it consumes all source before returning something, which will be passed to `Count`.

So, the only way to avoid iterating over all collection, is avoiding `OrderBy` - count items before sorting.

---

UPDATE: You can call this extension method on any `OrderedEnumerable` - it will use reflection to get `source` field of `OrderedEnumerable<T>` which holds source sequence. Then check if this sequence is collection, and use `Count` without executing ordering:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static int Count<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> ordered)
    {
        // you can check if ordered is of type OrderedEnumerable<T>
        Type type = ordered.GetType();
        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var field = type.GetField("source", flags);
        var source = field.GetValue(ordered);
        if (source is ICollection<T>)
            return ((ICollection<T>)source).Count;

        return ordered.Count();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var source = new[]{ 2, 4, 6, 1, 9 }.OrderBy(x => x);
int count = source.Count();
```

Comment: I know the code I posted does not avoid the OrderBy execution. That is why I am asking for a different way. But the IOrderedEnumerable created by OrderBy must keep a reference to the original list in order to do its defered exeuction business, so in theory it should be possible to get the count from that reference.

Comment: I was just experimenting with the same reflection idea - it works, though relying on private fields is something to be avoided if possible. There's presumably no guarantee the same field will exist in updates to the framework

Comment: @Rob there is no public way to get `source` from OrderedEnumerable, and class itself is internal. So, actually you even cannot be sure that `OrderedEnumerable<T>` will be returned by `OrderBy` in the updated framework. All you will have in a future is `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` inteface, which do not provide `source` to you. So, reflection is the only way to get source.

Comment: @lazyb - yes. I didn't mean to imply that there was a safer way to get hold of `source`. I meant that OP should think carefully whether the potential performance benefits of this approach outweigh the fragility.

Comment: @Rob OK :) Sorry, I thought that you are OP, thats why I pointed on why it is the only way. And yes, your comment is absolutely correct

Comment: You can also handle `ICollection coll = source as ICollection` so you support the non-generic collections too. And also if you check `field` for null, you can futureproof it to a certain extent (i.e. failover to the slow `Count()`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to create a performant solution i'd consider creating overloads that take either a collection or an IOrderedEnumerable etc.. all that "is " and "as" typechecking and casting can't be good for the kind of thing you are creating.

You are reinventing the wheel. linq's "Count()" function does pretty much as you want.

Also, add the this keyword and make this into a nifty extension method, to please yourself and other using the code.

```
DoSomething(this Collection source);
DoSomething<T>(this List<T> source);
DoSomething<T>(this IOrderedEnumerable<T> source);
```

etc...

Comment: The whole thing is an extension method with multiple overloads, I left that out of my simplified code example since it does not change the fundamental problem. The native Count() function specifically *cannot* do what I want: count an IOrderedEnumerable based on a list, without ordering the list.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to implement a class that implements `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`. You can then implement class members that will short-circuit the usual Linq extension methods, and provide a count method that looks at the original enumeration.

```
public class MyOrderedEnumerable<T> : IOrderedEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> Original;
    private IOrderedEnumerable<T> Sorted;

    public MyOrderedEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> orig)
    {
            Original = orig;
            Sorted = null;
    }

    private void ApplyOrder<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer, bool descending)
    {
            var before = Sorted != null ? Sorted : Original;
            if (descending)
                    Sorted = before.OrderByDescending(keySelector, comparer);
            else
                    Sorted = before.OrderBy(keySelector, comparer);
    }

    #region Interface Implementations

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
            return Sorted != null ? Sorted.GetEnumerator() : Original.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
            return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IOrderedEnumerable<T> CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>(
            Func<T, TKey> keySelector,
            IComparer<TKey> comparer,
            bool descending)
    {
            var newSorted = new MyOrderedEnumerable<T>(Original);
            newSorted.ApplyOrder(keySelector, comparer, descending);
            return newSorted;
    }

    #endregion Interface Implementations


    //Ensure that OrderBy returns the right type. 
    //There are other variants of OrderBy extension methods you'll have to short-circuit
    public MyOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<TKey>(Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    {   
            Console.WriteLine("Ordering");
            var newSorted = new MyOrderedEnumerable<T>(Original);
            newSorted.Sorted = (Sorted != null ? Sorted : Original).OrderBy(keySelector);
            return newSorted;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Fast counting..");
            var collection = Original as ICollection;
            return collection == null ? Original.Count() : collection.Count;
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
            var nums = new MyOrderedEnumerable<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,10).ToList());
            var nums2 = nums.OrderBy(x => -x);
            var z = nums.Count() + nums2.Count();
    }
}
```