# C#: IEnumerable<T>.Select() inefficient in some cases?

Tags: c#, linq

I recently learned that the objects created by .NET's LINQ implementation is inefficient for specific enumeration types.

Take a look at this code:

```
public class DummyCollection : ICollection<int>
{
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        public int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    //some more interface methods
}
```

basically, instances of DummyCollection have a size of 10, but throws an exception if it is actually enumerated.

now here:

```
var d = new DummyCollection();
Console.WriteLine(d.Count());
```

A 10 is printed without error, but this piece of code:

```
var l = d.Select(a=> a);
Console.WriteLine(l.Count());
```

throws an exception, despite it being trivial to say that l's size is 10 as well (since Select offers 1-to-1 mapping). What this basically means is, that when checking the length of an Ienumerable, the input might be a Select-wrapped Collection, thus extending the computation time from an O(1) to a staggering O(n) (could be even worse, if the selection function is particularly cumbersome).

I know that you sacrifice efficiency when you ask for LINQ's generics, but this seems like such a simple problem to fix. I checked online and couldn't find anyone addressing this. Is there a way to bypass this shortcoming? Is anyone looking into this? Is anyone fixing this? Is this just an edge case that isn't that much of a problem? Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Anyway, what would be a real use case of throwing an exception in `GetEnumerator` and being able to call `Count()` in any case...?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The exception throwing is just a placeholder to ensure that enumeration is avoided whenever possible. It could be replaced by a very long method call, or just a very large collection, or one that mutates upon enumerations (such as locking the object, which might be risky in an async environment).

Comment: `OrderBy` has the same problem. `OrderBy` will not change the count, but calling `Count()` still performs a full sort. You can get the correct count without sorting using some reflection shenaningans. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493076/count-an-iorderedenumerable-without-consuming-it

Comment: I would argue that by calling a LINQ method, you *expect* it to enumerate. It's like saying that `foreach` should avoid enumeration whenever possible. You want LINQ to protect users against using it inefficiently. But adding magic would make it very hard to reason about (and control) its behavior, esp. when methods are chained. I'd say "Don't do the crime, if you can't do the time."

Comment: @bentheiii And what's the point of avoiding enumerations if you implement `IEnumerable<T>`? If you don't want a given object to be enumerable, you don't implement the whole interface. Am I mistaken? :O

Answer (score 6):

You can see how `Count()` extension method is implemented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs). Basically is something like this:

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

    ICollection<TSource> collectionoft = source as ICollection<TSource>;

    if (collectionoft != null) return collectionoft.Count;

    ICollection collection = source as ICollection;

    if (collection != null) return collection.Count;

    int count = 0;
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        checked {
            while (e.MoveNext()) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

As you can see the method check first is the `source` is of type `ICollection<TSource>` or `ICollection`, if that is the case then there is no need to iterate counting the elements, just return `Count` property.

In your first case `Count` property is called returning `10` and `GetEnumerator()` method is never called.

When you use `Select()` method you're wrapping the collection into another type that isn't an `ICollection` (in above link you can also see `Select()` implementation), therefore the iteration is necessary.

In your second case, when you call `Count()` your `GetEnumerator()` method is called and the exception is thrown.

Comment: I realize this, I'm saying that that the Select method could be improved to return an ICollection<T>-type object (if the source is an ICollection<T> too) to optimize usages to the Count() method

Comment: @bentheiii: That's true. but probably wasn't implemented to keep lazy execution.

Comment: @bentheiii : LINQ is all about the lazy. Select doesn't return a collection of stuff. It returns something that, ***when you iterate it*** will pull an item at a time through the chain. The implication is that there's no storage when you `Select`. Storing the result in a collection would be disastrous to the intended use case of LINQ. Think about it like a pipeline where items are processed one at a time (in a very myopic fashion) rather than an operation that produces a (stored) collection.

Comment: @spender Then why not just return an object that wraps the input Collection? It's still lazy enumeration, and needs minimal space to store (not much more than the regular Select's enumerator, I don't think), but also maintains the ICollection Interface, with all the boons that come with.

Comment: @bentheiii What happens when your downstream user wants to use `ICollection<T>.Add` on your wrapped collection? Would you need to provide a reverse projection method? LINQ isn't really about collections, counts and indexes, but you have every opportunity to bring materialized collections into mix with extension methods such as `ToList`, `ToArray`, `ToDictionary` and `ToLookup`. Trying to shoehorn all of that into core LINQ would make it unwieldy (think of all the different types of feature detection that would need to occur) and, most likely, unworkable.

Comment: @spender Just set the Collection to be ReadOnly and throw an exception if Add is called. I realize this isn't what LINQ is designed around but it could be a real resource-saver, especially in cases of very large or virtual collections EDIT: besides, the user would need to actually cast the IEnumerable to an ICollection to call Add on it.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable<T>` doesn't have a concept of `Count`. This exists in implementations, which (apart from the odd shortcut here and there) have no role in LINQ to Objects. If you project an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` (such as `ICollection<T>`), with `Select`, the only real guarantee you have is that the output will be `IEnumerable<T>`... which has no `Count`.

LINQ should be thought of as dealing with sequences of items, one at a time, only with a concept of current and next item (or the end of sequence). Knowing about the number of items is a (potentially) costly operation that requires iteration of all the items being counted, other than in a few, optimized cases.

Given that LINQ ***relies*** on iteration in preference to indexes and counts means that an `IEnumerable` that errors when you try to iterate it is going to need some super weird special-casing to fly. To me, it wouldn't be a very useful use-case.